# How do you display EV3-G images properly on an NXT screen?

Tags: nxt, ev3-g

When I use the EV3 programming software to put an image on the screen of an NXT, it cuts off the top 3/4 of the image (see below):

```
       |
cut off|cut off
       |
----------------
       |
cut off|shown
       |
```

Only the bottom-right quarter of the image is showing. How can I make the brick show the entire image?

Comment: Could you please post the code you are using? Maybe we can spot the bug that way together.

Comment: A picture would be helpful too.

Comment: I'll try to put up a picture soon...